# Cross Platform shortcuts

Tags: windows, macos, shortcuts, cross-platform

I have a bunch of notes stored in plain text files about various topics I'm interested in. I organize them in a hierarchy of directories and use Windows shortcuts when a file could fit in more than one place. For example I have a file called `django.txt` which contains notes about the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) web framework. I keep the file in `/notes/python/django.txt`, but I have a shortcut in `/notes/servers` because it fits there too.

I just switched to OS X and all my shortcuts are broken, because Mac uses aliases instead. Is there anyway I could get cross OS shortcuts to work? Of course, I could just make both Mac alias and Windows shortcut files, but ideally I'd like to avoid cluttering things up too much.  Maybe I could use some note-taking program instead, but I like the simplicity and versatility of my plain text files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a simple [Document Management System](http://superuser.com/search?q=document+management)?

Comment: You could also try out [Notational Velocity](http://notational.net/). It has an option to store notes in plain text files, but doesn't support folders though (by design).

Comment: Yeah, I like Notational Velocity a lot.  Feel free to submit this as an answer if you want some points.

Comment: You can also create cross-platform internet "shortcuts" by creating HTML redirect pages. See here: http://superuser.com/a/538093/85129

Answer (score 3):

The web is the most common means of achieving X-platform compatibility.  It doesn't have to be something hosted on a web server, just run in a browser.

[Try TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/)

Comment: Looks cool.  But I think I would lose some of that versatility and simplicity I mentioned.  For example, I found spotlight worked very well with the system I described above.  I like being able to hit command-space and type in a "<foo> txt" and find the note I'm looking for.  txt files seem to "just work" in a wide variety of situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a web page that redirects to a file as a sort of "shortcut" to the file. The following .html file will redirect the browser to a file called `stuff.java` that is in the same folder as the shortcut:

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
    window.location.href = "stuff.java";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use relative folder paths: if `stuff.java` was inside a folder called `example-folder` in the same folder as the shortcut, then you would replace `"stuff.java"` with `example-folder/stuff.java`.